# A specific shape in C program

Tags: c, loops, shapes

I'm trying to do a specific shape in c.
I have to print line 1-4 again in lines 6-9 like that :

Total 9 lines :
line 6 same like line 4.
line 7 same like line 3.
line 8 same like line 2.
line 9 same like line 1.

Is there a way for doing it without back every line again?

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int
main ()
{
  int s, i, j;
 
  // for star
  printf ("Enter size (10-20)\n");
  scanf (" %d", &s);
  for (i = 1; i < 2; i++)
    {
      for (j = 1; j <= 2 * s - 1; j++)
    {
      if (j == s)
        printf ("o");
      else
        printf ("-");
 
    }
      printf ("\n");
    }
  for (i = 2; i < 3; i++)
    {
      for (j = 1; j <= 2 * s - 1; j++)
    {
      if (j == s + 1 || j == s - 1)
        printf ("o");
      else
        printf ("-");
    }
      printf ("\n");
    }
  for (i = 3; i < 4; i++)
    {
      for (j = 1; j <= 2 * s - 1; j++)
    {
      printf ("o");
    }
      printf ("\n");
    }
 
  for (i = 4; i < 5; i++)
    {
      for (j = 1; j <= 2 * s - 1; j++)
    {
      if (j == 2 * s - 2 || j == 2)
        printf ("o");
      else
        printf ("-");
    }
      printf ("\n");
    }
  for (i = 5; i < 6; i++)
    {
      for (j = 1; j <= 2 * s - 1; j++)
    {
      if (j == 2 * s - 3 || j == 3)
        printf ("o");
      else
        printf ("-");
    }
      printf ("\n");
    }
  // line 6 same like line 4
  // line 7 same like line 3
  // line 8 same like line 2
  // line 9 same like line 1
}
```

Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iItBQ.jpg)

It has to be like that in the end.

thanks guys i did it with functions.

Comment: You can write 4 functions, `line_1()`, `line_2()` and so on, and then call each of them twice.

Comment: Don't write it to the screen - write it to a string buffer so you can just print it out a second time.

Comment: As @rodrigo suggested, code to generate each distinct line should be in its own function. Then call each function appropriately. Note, also, that there is vertical symmetry. Define the left 10 characters in a string (simple), then print that string forward, middle character, then print the string backwards. So, each of the 4 functions calls the worker function to do the work. Program should be only 20-25 lines long.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all the loops - you can just use strcpy and strcat.  And if you store the results in different buffers you can use them more than once.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int size;
    char line1[21];
    char line2[21];
    char line3[21];
    char line4[21];
    char line5[21];

    printf ("Enter size (10-20)\n");
    scanf ("%d", &size);

    strncpy(line1,"---------------------",size);
    strcat(line1,"o");
    strncat(line1,"---------------------",size);

    strncpy(line2,"---------------------",size-1);
    strcat(line2,"o-o");
    strncat(line2,"---------------------",size-1);

    strncpy(line3,"ooooooooooooooooooooo",2*size+1);

    strcpy(line4,"-o");
    strncat(line4,"---------------------",2*size-3);
    strcat(line4,"o-");

    strcpy(line5,"--o");
    strncat(line5,"---------------------",2*size-5);
    strcat(line5,"o--");

    puts(line1);
    puts(line2);
    puts(line3);
    puts(line4);
    puts(line5);
    puts(line4);
    puts(line3);
    puts(line2);
    puts(line1);

    return 0;
}
```

Try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/NUPh1gxA9

Comment: Hey, be aware that it’s not the same pattern like I need. I uploaded the photo with the desirable pattern.

Comment: @AC7 Sorry - I read the question wrong.  I have fixed the code.